# Disable rotation in one tab of tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I disable rotation only in one tab of tab bar?
I've tried this code, but the view still rotates, but flips back to portrait.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
    {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
        {
            int orientationPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
            NSMethodSignature *sig = [[UIDevice currentDevice] methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)];
            NSInvocation* invo = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
            [invo setTarget:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
            [invo setSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)];
            [invo setArgument:&orientationPortrait atIndex:2];
            [invo invoke];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Complete solution is [here](https://github.com/pronebird/TabBarOrientationExample):

```
static const NSInteger kPortraitOnlyTabIndex = 1;

@interface TabBarController : UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation TabBarController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)tabBarControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController {
    if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == kPortraitOnlyTabIndex) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];

    if([self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController] == kPortraitOnlyTabIndex) {
        SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:");
        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:sel]) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
            [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:sel withObject:(__bridge id)((void*)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
        }
    }
}

@end
```